# Fingerprint in Javascript on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap, android-fingerprint-api

I´m creating my first app ever for a school project with Phonegap. I have everything working besides fingerprint scanner. I have looked on Google, but I don´t quite understand what to do. It tells me to write some commands in an console, which I doesn´t know where to find.

I currently got this files in the project:

- index.js
- config.xml
- format.css
- index.html

Could anyone please point me in the right direction for getting a working fingerprint scanner?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a modern IDE (like Atom, WebStorm, etc.) so you have access to a console.

How are you getting your program to run locally without a console?

Alternatively, if you are on a mac you can go to the Terminal, and then navigate to the folder, and run commands from there.

Hope that helps